# How to open browser along with all plugins taht i added on browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
@Test
public void captchImage() throws IOException
{
    File file = new File("extension.xpi");
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.addExtension(file);
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
    driver.get("http://njdg.ecourts.gov.in/njdg_public/index.php");
```

I want to open firefox browser along with plugin[i attached image please go through that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNCy5.png)

Comment: What is `extension.xpi`?

Comment: Code is seems right, provided path to xpi file is correct (is it?). Which Firefox are you using, and is your extension signed? Latest FF doesn't like unsigned extensions. I suggest pausing the test when browser is open and checking whether extension is there, and whether it's enabled (it might be installed but not enabled)

Comment: @KirilS. my extension is signed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to launch your plugin like this, rather use ProfileIni to launch the profile required.
[Profile management in Selenium](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/)

Store your extension in a profile and then get that profile name and launch it in your browser.
Launching specific profile.

```
ProfileIni pro=new ProfileIni();
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile profile=pro.getProfile("ProfileName");
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(profile)
```

Comment: Hello sir, i am not getting can you explain more, i am a beginner, so having difficulty to understand

Comment: ProfilesIni pro=new ProfilesIni();
  org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile profile=pro.getProfile("avnishrathor03@gmail.com");
  WebDriver d=new FirefoxDriver(profile);
  d.manage().window().maximize();
  d.get("http://njdg.ecourts.gov.in/njdg_public/index.php");

Comment: Have you created the profile how it is mentioned in the link?

Comment: can you please provide the link

Comment: Thank you sir, Now it is working. But i got new issue like after created profile and again installed my plugins now i am not able to use firebug extension

Comment: Dear Avnish cause you have installed firebug on the default profile if you want to use firebug again, then install it for that profile as well. And do accept the answer if it helped thanks